# azureml how to deploy docker image to webservice

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Try to containerize models using docker and use this in a web service. Getting the following error "azureml.exceptions._azureml_exception.WebserviceException: WebserviceException:Message: Models must either be of type azureml.core.Model or a str path to a file or folder".

```
    env = Environment.from_conda_specification("env", "../Environments.yml")
    inf_conf = InferenceConfig(
    entry_script="score.py",
    environment=env)


    docker_image = Model.package(ws, [models_latest], inf_conf)
    docker_image.wait_for_creation(show_output=True) 



    # Deploy the image
    webservice_name = os.environ['WEB_SERVICE_NAME']

    retries = 2
    while retries > 0:
        try:
            service = AciWebservice(workspace = ws,
                                    name = webservice_name)
            service.update(image = docker_image)
            print('Webservice updated')   
        except:
            print('Webservice not found')
            service = Webservice.deploy_from_image(workspace = ws,
                                                name = webservice_name,
                                                image = docker_image,
                                                deployment_config = aciconfig)

        # wait for deployment, get logs if failed
        try:
            service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
            break
        except:
            print(service.get_logs())
            retries -= 1
            if retries == 0:
                raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the YAML file into the accurate environment including the path using the following command.

```
conda activate myenv
```

Replace myenv with your virtual environment.

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

export this active environment to the new file (YAML file)
Make the model as standard PKL file and assign that pickle file as an input.

**Example when the model is a file**

```
model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), 'sklearn_regression_model.pkl')
```

**Example when the model is a folder containing a file**

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), 'my_model_folder', 'sklearn_regression_model.pkl')
```

For connecting docker image to web server properly, [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73414794/azureml-how-to-create-a-webservice-from-docker-image/73467076#73467076)