# azureml how to create a webservice from docker image

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Got all machine learning model that i have registered into a docker image using model package. How do I deploy this docker image to a web service

```
# Define the deployment configuration
aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(
      cpu_cores = 1,
      memory_gb = 1,
      dns_name_label = os.environ['ACI_DNS_NAME_LABEL'])


#create env 
environment = Environment('env')
environment.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=[
'pip==20.2.4'],
 pip_packages=[
 'azureml-defaults',
 'joblib',
 'numpy',
 'scikit-learn'])

    
inf_conf = InferenceConfig(entry_script="score.py",environment=environment)
#crete docker image    
docker_image = Model.package(ws,models_latest, inf_conf,image_name="imgname")
docker_image.wait_for_creation(show_output=True) 
docker_image.pull()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the deployment, we need to have a trained model handy for the deployment. As the trained model is available and the process needs to be deployed as a web service.

Check out the procedure of creating a container resource for the web app.

[image]

Click on “**create a resource**”

[image]

Click on “**Container**” in the left panel

[image]

Click on **Web App** for **Containers** and click on **create**

[image]

Give the details required and keep the container details handy for further usage.

```
docker_image = Model.package(ws,models_latest, inf_conf,image_name="imgname")
docker_image.wait_for_creation(show_output=True) 
docker_image.pull()
```

After the `**image.pull()**` method was used, we will get the process notification regarding the docker image which we created.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for myworkspacef78fd10.azurecr.io/package:packagenumber
```

After downloading the docker image, user the command “`docker images`” to get the list of local images

```
REPOSITORY          name.azurecr.io/package
TAG                 Your docker tag
IMAGE ID            Your Image ID
CREATED             Time created
SIZE                Size of the container
```

The data contains the `<image id>` which we need to replace in the below syntax

```
docker run -p 6789:5001 --name containername <imageid>
```

`**6789**` is the local port number and **`5001`** is the web service listening number.

Create a Dockerfile and dependencies

```
package = Model.package(ws, [model], inference_config, generate_dockerfile=True)
package.wait_for_creation(show_output=True)
# Download the package.
package.save("./imagefiles")
# Get the Azure container registry that the model/Dockerfile uses.
acr=package.get_container_registry()
print("Address:", acr.address)
print("Username:", acr.username)
print("Password:", acr.password)
```

the above code block helps us to download the files required to build the image in `**imagefiles**` directory.

We need to use the shell to authenticate the docker image

```
docker login <address> -u <username> -p <password>
```

Now, build the docker image

```
docker build --tag myimage <imagefiles>
```

To run the container use the command below, which is listening based on the port and web service number.

```
docker run -p 6789:5001 --name mycontainer image_name:latest
```